# Why is my array not being passed to my other controller method?

Tags: methods, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I am working in VS13 - MVC 5 and I'm having an issue with passing data from one controller method to another (in the same controller).

This is the last bit of code in a HttpPost controller method that works fine, that is I've stepped through it and verified that the data is being passed into the redirecttoaction method in the bottom, which you can see below:

```
        ...<irrelevant code that works fine on top>...
        int[] idArray = new int[questionsToUse.Count];
        for (var i=0; i<questionsToUse.Count; i++)
        {
            idArray[i] = questionsToUse[i].QuestionId;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ShowQuiz", new { array = idArray  });
    }
```

And this is the controller method that is being redirected to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowQuiz(int[] array)
    {
        var caseToShow = new Medcase();
        caseToShow.Title = "Quiz";
        caseToShow.Questions = new List<Question>();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
        {
            caseToShow.Questions.Add(db.Questions.Find(i));
        }
        return View(caseToShow);
    }
```

I put breakpoints on both methods and stepped through them, as mentioned the first method works fine down to the last redirecttoaction line where I can see the data is there as I set the parameter.

But as soon as I step into the next method the array value is just null everytime? Can anyone explain to me why this is? I've used this method succesfully on other methods, where I simply passed a single int value to the other method. Does this have to do with me not being able to pass array or something? Or is it because it's happening at the end of a httppost method (the redirect)?

I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong, all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found out that it's because I'm putting it in an array, when I pass a single value it works fine... can anyone tell me if there is a type of collection I can use which is possible to transfer?

Comment: I found out how to solve this using "TempData".

Comment: You can't pass complex types because you are performing a redirect. It's not like calling a method. You'd have to serialize the data in order to pass the array.

Comment: It's possible to send lists of object using the TempData methodology and it's working right now so... yes I can.

Comment: Yes using tempdata it's possible, not through the route values as you attempted in your question..

Comment: No I figured that out after tinkering with it for a while, but it's good to know for future reference. I'm not sure if I should just delete this question or what?

Comment: Respond to your own question with an answer of what worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use the a feature called "TempData" this way you can pass any collection (with objects aswell) to another controller method.

The changes to my code looks like this, starting with the bottom of the beforementioned post method.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsToUse.Count; i++)
        {
            questionIds[i] = questionsToUse[i].QuestionId;
        }
        TempData["quizquestionids"] = questionIds;
        return RedirectToAction("ShowQuiz");
    }
```

I simply pass my array into the tempdata and give it a name of my own choosing.

Then I extract the collection from the method I wanna use it in and do whatever I need.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowQuiz()
    {
        var caseToShow = new Medcase();
        caseToShow.Title = "Quiz";
        var questionIds = TempData["quizquestionids"] as int[];
```

Fairly simple and working solution to the problem.